# What's the name of this "bubble" for selecting the cursor position?

Tags: android, cursor

I am trying implement something similar to this "drop" or "bubble under cursor" used in Android for selecting cursor position, pasting, etc. but I am having trouble to find the name of it.

Bonus, if somebody tell me a js library for doing something similar

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

These bubbles are called **Text Selection Handles** in Android.

> Reference: [Material Design: Patterns – Selection](https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/selection.html#)